# How generate a sequence of dates in open office

Tags: openoffice.org

In Excel, it´s possible to create a sequence of dates and autofill this sequence e.g. from 01.01.2005 to 01.01.2025. In Excel, it is right-click on the edge of the cell and "row". There I can type the beginning and the end of that sequence. Where is this function in open office?